# TreeMap conversion to the List as per the object hierarchy

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, tree, treemap

This is my treemap structure

```
01->01-01
  ->01-02
```

01 is the parent element and 01-01 and 01-02 are child elements of 01.

This is my Object strucutre

```
List
 -ObjectA
   -SubList
     -ObjectA
     -ObjectA
```

Is it possible to convert the treemap to my object structure hierarchically. Meaning I want child elements to be in the SubList of the ObjectA(which is parent element)

Comment: Please share what you have tried ?

Comment: now Im manually adding the objects to its place which is not generic and have to do it for each level. Implemented the treemap to the data but when i convert to the list all the objects are in the same level just like any other list